# Pseudocode for the ordered dithering of an X *Y monochrome image

Tags: image-processing, dithering

I have been given the assignment to write a pseudo code for the ordered dithering of an x*y monochrome image I using D as a threshold map. Can anybody please help me

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: You will find that easily by Web search.